# How to integrate Watson IOT service to Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, watson-iot

Due to IBM doesn't provide free plan for IBM Blockchain anymore, I come up with with solution to integrate Watson IOT to Hyperledger Fabric instead of IBM Blockchain.
I found this document, it say that Watson IoT Platform blockchain integration supports connecting to both IBM Blockchain fabrics and Hyperledger fabrics
[(in section Config Blockchain IBM environment)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/blockchain/dev_blockchain.html#iotblockchain_link)

But I can not find any guideline.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

I have several related comments:

1) The page you linked to shows an early version of the IoT Contract Platform that I authored. I have not been funded to port it to Hyperledger v1 so it must be considered deprecated at this time. Instead, I suggest that you get comfortable with the Hyperledger Composer, which provides a huge development environment and a powerful data modelling language.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/introduction/introduction.html

2) Which leads me to IBM's free container service. If you want to get started with IBM Blockchain on Bluemix, you can create a free kubernetes cluster using the instructions found here.

https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/

The "create_all" script gives you a working fabric on a lite cluster (as in free) with hyperledger composer running (with playground) and with a copy of the example02 ubiquitous sample Go chaincode running on the same channel.

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-container-service

EDIT: As for the iot connection, you can use node-red to create iot apps that will catch your events on a topic and then forward them to the blockchain. This is for experimentation of course, but you will get the idea how an application must be written.

If you want to follow my ["partial state as event"](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/blockchain-samples/blob/master/docs/HyperledgerContractsIntroBestPracticesPatterns.md) pattern in composer contracts, you can look at the deep-merge npm project and mimick that code while we wait for the node based chaincode that is coming in Fabric 1.1, at which time I hope that we can import it as normal in our business network js files.

Using deep-merge requires that you create your own transactions for create, replace, update and delete in your smart contracts, but these are straightforward. The bonus is that it is also easy then to emit custom events defining what happened to listening applications.

I think you will like these two technologies together.

Comment: Thanks @Kim. Due to  I'm not familiar with IBM container service, could you give me the architecture of this solution, how Hyperledger Composer, kubernetes and Watson IoT interact with each others. I'm stuck in "Create a cluster on IBM Container Service" step when follow your instruction. It require upgrade account to create cluster. I already request with my visa info and send email to accounting@softlayer.com as require but still not receive any response. What should I do now ?

Comment: The Watson IoT Platform is an MQTT broker with integration infrastructure to the IBM Cloud. You route devices there and catch the incoming messages on topics. When you have something to send to the blockchain (device msgs or asset state changes), you format a message for a smart contract transaction and send it to Composer on the container service Kubernetes cluster. (Or use SDK and send to your own chaincode.) Sample clusters run Composer, a set of peers, a set of CouchDB instances for history and state tracking, and of course an ordering service and CA / MSP. I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the IBM Blockchain, you should create your own Blockchain. You should use the Hyperledger Fabric for that. You have the documentacion about it [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/). I suggest you to start reading from the Building Your First Network chapter.

Then, you should integrate your Blockchain with the Watson IoT.

Comment: The link you have given doesn't work. Can you update it?

Comment: I've just changed it